# Does Chewie still owe a life debt to Han according to the Solo film?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo, chewbacca, solo-a-star-wars-story

During *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, we see

> Han and Chewbacca's first time meeting. There's clear allusions to Legends in how it goes down (Han as an Imperial, helping free Chewie, a captive, and being on the run from the Empire afterwards).

However, the way this goes down

> means that Han didn't rescue Chewie so much as they worked together to escape. Han made no sacrifice, which means it no longer makes sense for Chewie to owe him a life debt. This is supported by the fact that it never comes up during the movie, and instead we see a strong inference that Chewbacca sticks around simply because he chooses to.

Up until now, even in canon we still see it commonly stated that much of why Chewie does what he does is because of the life debt he owes Han. Would it now be safe to assume that this is no longer true of their relationship?

Comment: It's disney, continuity/logic is not their strong suit

Comment: @GarretGang - in what way? The LucasFilm Story Group has, in my opinion, done a fantastic job of keeping all the various media lines in sync. Are there specific examples related to the new Star Wars canon you can cite?

Comment: Life debt is certainly not portrayed in this movie (maybe it did happen latter ) and there is an implication that Chewbacca was fed with human flesh. Certainly one of those Disney moments ;)

Comment: We see other things in the movie which could be construed as Han saving Chewie's life.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Solo film should be taken into consideration with the rest of the Disney canon. According to the post ROTJ book "Life Debt" - Han says:

> "I saved him, at least that's what he says, the big fuzzy fool, but
>   really, he saved me. I was on a bad path, and Chewie, he put me
>   straight. Saved my shanks more than once, too. He said it was part of
>   some *life debt* - he has a word for it, but if I try to say it in his
>   tongue I'll probably strain something. Even if I can't say it, I know
>   what it means. It means that he owes his life to me." - Star Wars: Aftermath - Life Debt

Whether or not the life debt came from this particular meeting is currently unknown, but Han and Chewie both still think Chewie owes Han a life debt post-ROTJ

** note: the canon book "Star Wars: Last Shot" may have some additional information but I haven't read that yet :)*